# UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Let's get to the problem 
I have a page where I want users to fill info about themselves, and i would like to save that data. But I'm getting this error.

`IntegrityError at /accounts/profile/edit/1/change-profile/
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username`

this is my view.py

```
def change_profile(request, pk):
    form = ChangeProfile(request.POST or None)
    user_ = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/accounts/profile/edit/{}/".format(user_.pk))
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'change_profile.html', args)
```

my models.py

```
class GradeUser(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = 'email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
        )
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='username')
    grade = models.ForeignKey(GradeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='accounts/media', blank=True)
    about_me = models.TextField()


    USERNAME_FIELD= 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()
```

forms.py

```
class ChangeProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('real_name', 'grade', 'country', 'about_me')
```

What does exactly go wrong?

Why would it need a user's username?

What should I do with it to save?

Comment: You want to update the current logged in user's information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aim to perform an update on your User (that already exists) but here you are creating a whole new user instance with no username attribute and that's what generates the error.
Try this code : it gets your current user and updates it with the info provided from the form.

PS : I did not modify anything about the returns because I dunno what you're doing there but note that you don't need to pass the user pk through the arguments, the user data is already stored in the request object.

```
def change_profile(request, pk):
form = ChangeProfile()
user_ = request.user
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ChangeProfile(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_new_info=form.save(commit=false)
        user_.real_name = user_new_info.real_name
        user_.grade = user_new_info.grade
        user_.country = user_new_info.country
        user_.about_me = user_new_info.about_me
        user_.save()
        return redirect("/accounts/profile/edit/{}/".format(user_.pk))
args = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'change_profile.html', args)
```

Comment: Could the ModelForm `ChangeProfile` be initialised with the current user using `instance=` somehow?

Comment: I dont know if there is a way to do so but I have my own way of doing it. In my html, I set the inputs value with the current user's data. For example : <input  type="text" name="{{form.username.name}}" value="{{ user.username }}"> . So when I post the form, it posts that value ! It's not the most elegant way but it does the job. Did you get what I meant ?

Comment: Yes I used to do this as well, but with `ModelForm`s there are more elegant ways as you said ^^

Comment: Actually, I just searched and found the "more elegant" way of doing it, when you instanciate your form in views, set initial values like this for example : form = UserForm(initial={'username': request.user.username}, instance=request.user). It's right that it 'fills' the form with initial values but careful, it still creates a new User instance ! Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)  for more information

Comment: Thank you very much